# SQL Select Rows that have same column value

Tags: sql

I Have following table, I Would like to Select rows  that have same value in Zone field for the same Line number.

| Id | Line | Name | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A | 2 |
| 2 | 10 | B | 2 |
| 3 | 15 | C | 3 |
| 4 | 15 | D | 4 |
| 5 | 17 | E | 5 |
| 6 | 17 | F | 5 |
| 7 | 17 | G | 6 |
| 8 | 20 | H | 7 |
| 9 | 20 | I | 7 |

Result should be:

| Id | Line | Name | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A | 2 |
| 2 | 10 | B | 2 |
| 8 | 20 | H | 7 |
| 9 | 20 | I | 7 |

What's the correct way to query this?

Comment: I cannot see a pattern here, could you clarify the question?

Comment: GROUP BY line and zone, and use HAVING COUNT(*)>1  and you can select from your original table using these lines and zones.

Comment: `select * from ztable zt where exists(select * from ztable x where x.line=zt.line and x.zone = zt.zone and x.id <> zt.id);`

Answer (score 0):

One way is using EXISTS

```
Select Id, Line, Name, Zone
from tbl t
where not exists (
      select 1 
      from tbl t2 
      where t2.Line = t1.Line and t2.Zone <> t1.Zone)
```